# Почему не хватает одного элемента при создании массива через new Array(n)?

Tags: javascript

Почему код

```js
let arr = new Array(5).join('5');
console.log(arr);
```

возвращает четыре пятерки а не 5 ?

Comment: Потому что между 5-ю элементами (пустыми в данном случае) 4 символа-разделителя (`'5'` в данном случае)

Comment: `new Array(5).fill("5").join("");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

> Метод join() объединяет все элементы массива (или массивоподобного объекта) в строку.

[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array#array_constructor_with_a_single_parameter)

> Массивы можно создавать с помощью конструктора с одним числовым параметром. Массив, length свойство которого установлено на это число, а элементы массива являются **пустыми слотами**.

Таким образом, Вы создаёте массив, элементами которого являются `undefined`, и соединяете их между собой, разделяя их строкой `5`

Answer (score 2):

Потому что метод `join` не делает то, что Вы думаете.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

```js
console.log(new Array(5));
```